# Unable to locate webelement in popup window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble with automating test on website https://casino.efortuna.ro/en/

whatever I do, selenium is not able to find inputs for username/password

I have already tried  driver.switchTo().activeElement() and    driver.switchTo().frame(0) and nothing seems to be working.

this code is supposed to find them and fill them but will always fail with

**"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="view389"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"}"**

```
public CasinoMainPage openLoginForm() {
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"application\"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"));
        loginBtn.click();
        return this;
    }
         public CasinoMainPage fillUsername(String username) {
        WebElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view389\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"););
        loginField.sendKeys(username);
        return this;
    }

    public CasinoMainPage fillPassword(String password) {
        WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view185\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/input"););
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
        return this;
    }


 //this method is called from @Test and fails on Fillusername()

public CasinoMainPage login() {
        goToMainPage();
        waitFor(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"application\"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button");,Const.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        openLoginForm();
        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        fillUsername("login");
        fillPassword("password");
        commitLogin();
        return this;
    }
```

can you please help me? I can't find out what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: username xpath - //*[@name="userName"]

Comment: password xpath - //*[@name="password"] --> This has to work fine

Comment: @santhoshkumar Any specific reason to avoid `name` locator for `username` and `password`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can consider to change the following:

1. `Login` button on Homepage:

   ```
   WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn_action_login btn_size_small fn-login']"));
   ```
2. `Username` field:

   ```
   WebElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
   ```
3. `Password` field:

   ```
   WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
   ```
4. `LOG IN` button:

   ```
   WebElement LOG_IN = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn fn-login-btn btn_type_popup-login']"));
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: working !!  thank you very much.  just a question how did you export those xpaths as chrome F12 and firebug returns me what i had there before